# not get token and FCM notification on device

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am integrate FCM in my app.Sent fcm from Firebase but not display on device.I am trying notification display when my app foreground and background.

1-:connect app to Firebase and  add FCM to my app.(Android Studio-->Tools-->Firebase-->Cloud Messaging)

2-:Create MyFirebaseMessageingService1 Class and extends by FirebaseMessagingService and implement Method (onNewToken and onMessageReceived)

3-:create method genrateNotification in onMessageReceived

4-:add this service in manifest file and add action com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT

```
 private void genrateNotification(String body, String title) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
       PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
         Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
         NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                 .setContentTitle(title)
                 .setContentText(body)
                 .setAutoCancel(true)
                 .setSound(soundUri)
                 .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

         NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

         if(NOTIFICATION_ID > 1073741824){
             NOTIFICATION_ID =0;
                     }
                     notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++,notificationBuilder.build());
     }
```

not get token and notification after implement above code

Comment: Check by log in onMessageReceived() method. First check your Settings. Make the Notification Priority t High and then Check INTERNET Premission in Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Before retrieving token make sure:

- Your device is connected with Internet.
- App is connected to `firebase` successfully.
- You have latest `GooglePlayServices` installed on device.

Now ,to retrieve token any time you need:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                return;
            }

            // Get new Instance ID token
            String token = task.getResult().getToken();

            // Log and toast
            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Your `MyNotificationService` class:

```
    public class MyNotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            String channelId = "Default";

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                    .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Default channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
            manager.notify(0, builder.build());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNewToken(String s) {
            super.onNewToken(s);
            Log.d(TAG, "NewToken: " + s);
        }
}
```

In your manifest:

```
<service
        android:name=".MyNotificationService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: NotificationCompat.Bulider I pass only this not channel id.error: constructor Builder in class Builder cannot be applied to given types;

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#notificationcompat.builder_1 see this

Comment: here my compile and target sdk version is 28